# How do I programmatically determine if a type is natively serializable by protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

I am dynamically creating a RuntimeTypeModel by reflecting over types. When I reflect over a type, I look at each of its properties and determine the tag (using my own mechanism) and add it to the `MetaType`. I also need to determine whether the type of the property is a nested message in itself rather than a primitive that is natively serializable by protobuf-net, so that I can recursively process that type as well, thereby adding it to the model and making the outer type serializable by protobuf-net.

For example, let's say I am reflecting over the following type:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Bar InnerMessage { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    TimeSpan Duration { get; set; } 
}
```

I've been asked to serialize `Foo` and for each type of each of its properties I need to determine  whether I need to add it to the model as a new `MetaType` or not. Obviously, the `int`,`string` and `TimeSpan` types do not need to be added to the model, but `Bar` does. How would I make this distinction programmatically? Do I need to hardcode this logic (with a `switch` block or an `if`-`else` chain)? If so, what types does protobuf-net r480 natively support (i.e. adding them to the model will throw an `ArgumentException` stating that *"Data of this type has inbuilt behaviour, and cannot be added to a model in this way"*)?

Comment: Is determing if the propertype is a ValueType, a String or something else not enough?

Comment: @rene: Unfortunately no. A `ValueType` could be a custom struct that needs to be handled. Also, special types are supported such as `TimeSpan` (not in `TypeCode`), `byte[]`, `Guid`, `Uri` and possibly other classes/structs. And native support for `Nullable<>`, array/collection/list/dictionary, etc.

Comment: I assume Marc Gravell will popup on this question but in the source here: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net/Helpers.cs there is at line 288 a function that could help you, if it was not in an internal class...

Comment: I'm not even sure that `GetTypeCode()` would help me, even if it was public. What if the type of the property is `int[]`? `GetTypeCode()` would return `ProtoTypeCode.Unknown` and yet it is natively serializable by protobuf-net. Enums are special-cased as well. It really is quite complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

r583 adds support for this, by extending the current `CanSerializeContractType`; there is now a `CanSerializeBasicType`, and an over-arching `CanSerialize`. As before, this retains the existing support for handling nullable types, lists (non-nested) and 1-dimensional arrays.